# VisualSVN Server, how to list users?

Tags: svn, svn-server, visualsvn-server, visualsvn

I have about 60 VisualSVN Server repositories and few sub-repositories in my VisualSVN Server and I need information on users assigned to each repository and permissions assigned to them.

Listing manually takes more time and I'm afraid I might miss someone.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`Get-SvnAccessRule`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/#Get-SvnAccessRule) cmdlet to generate such report.